# enableJIT in Rprofile leads to 'not a proper evaluation environment' on startup

Tags: r

I have had

```
library(compiler)
compiler::enableJIT(3)
```

in `~/.Rprofile` for years; now that I upgraded to **3.2.1** I get this on startup:

```
Error in frameTypes(env) : not a proper evaluation environment
Calls: <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous> -> makeCenv -> structure -> frameTypes
> q()
Warning message:
restarting interrupted promise evaluation
```

I don't see anything relevant in [NEWS](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html).

Replacing `3` with `2` in `compiler::enableJIT(3)` removes the error.
However, I would prefer my loops to be compiled too.

Suggestions?

PS. I observe the same behavior on MacOSX 10.10.4 (R downloaded from [cran](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/R-3.2.1.pkg)) and CentOS 6.6 (R installed using `yum`).

Comment: Sounds like a question for the Rdevel mailing list.

Comment: That mailing list does expect details of your OS and how R was installed. Some Linux problems occur when the dev-version of R was not installed, but I have no idea whether that is an issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a subtle "thinko" (confusing the base namespace environment with the base environment) in the new fast `topenv()` function which made it into the source code of R in **January** ... it would really have been great if you had upgraded sooner..... or even tried "R-devel" so this buglet would never have seen the light of day in a released version of R.

***Please, please,  all ye readers*** : Do help open source projects such as R by at least using the very latest released versions, .. even better, do occasionally run everyting with "R-devel" --- the development version of R, available via svn, git and most conveniently for installation from the daily snapshot tarballs at http://stat.ethz.ch/R/daily/

Comment: so, this is a known bug, right? has it been fixed? when? do you have a link to the official bug tracker?

Comment: @sds: well it is a known bug **now** that you wrote about it to the 'R-devel' mailing list and we saw it. Here's more: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2015-August/071606.html   where I do write that it is fixed.. and more.

Comment: Thanks - for *me* the lesson learned is that _nobody_ does `compiler::enableJIT(3)` and, thus, I shouldn't either.

Comment: Speaking about pre-testing R - I only build software to which I contribute source code. Unless I can get the daily builds of R using `apt-get`, this is not happening.